# Linux Mint fails to install GRUB

Tags: linux-mint, boot, grub2, dual-boot, grub

I'm a complete beginner.

I recently wanted to try to dual-boot my computer that already had `Windows 11` on it, adding `Linux Mint`. I created a USB using Rufus, choosing GPT, as my system is recent. I disabled Secure Boot, and made sure my computer didn't have BitLocker. Afterwards, I booted with the USB using Windows' "Advanced Restart" feature. I then Installed Linux Mint as usual, choosing to keep Windows Boot Manager. I let 100GB for Linux, and the rest for Windows. However, coming to the end of the install, I got a fatal error saying:

```
Executing 'grub-install /dev/nvme0n1' failed. This is a fatal error.
```

It then said that Linux Mint was installed successfully and prompted to restart now. However when I did, I obviously got booted back to Windows. I installed `Grub2Win`, but it couldn't detect Linux Mint, despite detecting a `Linux Filesystem`. Please help!

Comment: You absolutely shouldn't disable Secure Boot if running Windows 11. It has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Shut down Win 11 completely. Hold down the power switch for 15 seconds. Boot with the Mint install media. Select 'advanced options > rescue system'. Advanced options are on the menu of the installation disk. Open a root shell, and run `grub-install && update-grub` Grub will add Win 11 as a boot option. Disable Win fast startup. I hope this helps.

Comment: Where can I find the adanced options? @Brian

Comment: Not entirely correct. First of all you should explain what it means by a complete shutdown. Even better, you should always recommend disabling the Windows' Fast Startup "feature" for any dual-boot, no exceptions. @Elie07 The advance options should be in the first Grub menu.